# jquery on click event to disiplay the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do like  in the page http://www.ovariancancer.org/
the problem is in the with the class **event_content** I need to display only limited content, when content is crossed the  the limited content i need to hide and then when i click on the class **plus** I need to display all the content.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".plus").click(function(){
        alert('hi sudheer');
        $(".event_content").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.event_profit{
  background: #ecece9;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  height:180px;
  }  

.plus{
  width:5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.event_content p{
 margin: 10px 0;
}
.maincontainer{
 width:100%;
 display: -webkit-inline-box;

}
.event_image{
  width: 15%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top:1%;
}

.event_content{
 width: 70%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event_profit">
 
 <div class="maincontainer">
 
  <div class="event_image">
  
  <img src="http://www.charitywater.org/blog/../../_files/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/blog-charity-water-thank-you-instameets.png" class="img-circle" style="height:150px;width:150px">
 
  </div>
  
  <div class="event_content">
   <p>
   </p>
   <p>  Angelina Jolie Pitt recently announced that she has had her ovaries and fallopian tubes removed in order to reduce her risk of ovarian cancer. 
     Ms. Jolie Pitt had previous shared that she has a mutation in the BRCA gene, which increases her risk of breast and ovarian cancers. 
     The Alliance received many calls and requests to comment from media outlets; expand this story for links to some of our news coverage.
   </p>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="plus">
   <img src="http://www.ovariancancer.org/wp-content/themes/ovariancancer/images/plus2.png" style="width:33px;height:33px;"/>
  </div>
 
 </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Content is already slideddown so what you are looking for is probably `slideToggle`.

Comment: for the content I have give height, if the height of content is more i need to display limited content, when I click on plus it show all the content div

Comment: have a look at my solution :) first hide a div containing what you dont want to show, then toggle a class to show the content of that div :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can just adjust the height of the content to a fixed height and .css or .animate it with jquery on click to height: auto; Cant get the button to work in a snippet, jquery most likely missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".plus").click(function(){
        alert('hi sudheer');
        $(".event_content").css({ 'height' : 'auto' });
    });
});
```

```css
.event_profit{
  background: #ecece9;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  height:180px;
  }  

.plus{
  width:5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.event_content p{
 margin: 10px 0;
}
.maincontainer{
 width:100%;
 display: -webkit-inline-box;

}
.event_image{
  width: 15%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top:1%;
}

.event_content{
 width: 70%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  height: 47px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event_profit">
 
 <div class="maincontainer">
 
  <div class="event_image">
  
  <img src="http://www.charitywater.org/blog/../../_files/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/blog-charity-water-thank-you-instameets.png" class="img-circle" style="height:150px;width:150px">
 
  </div>
  
  <div class="event_content">
   <p>
   </p>
   <p>  Angelina Jolie Pitt recently announced that she has had her ovaries and fallopian tubes removed in order to reduce her risk of ovarian cancer. 
     Ms. Jolie Pitt had previous shared that she has a mutation in the BRCA gene, which increases her risk of breast and ovarian cancers. 
     The Alliance received many calls and requests to comment from media outlets; expand this story for links to some of our news coverage.
   </p>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="plus">
   <img src="http://www.ovariancancer.org/wp-content/themes/ovariancancer/images/plus2.png" style="width:33px;height:33px;"/>
  </div>
 
 </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Have an extra div to show the complete summary

***HTML***

```
<div class="event_profit">

    <div class="maincontainer">

        <div class="event_image">

        <img src="http://www.charitywater.org/blog/../../_files/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/blog-charity-water-thank-you-instameets.png" class="img-circle" style="height:150px;width:150px">

        </div>

        <div class="event_content" >
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>  Angelina Jolie Pitt recently announced that she has had her ovaries and fallopian tubes removed in order to reduce her risk of ovarian cancer. 
                 Ms. Jolie Pitt had previous shared that she has a mutation in the BRCA gene, which increases her risk of breast and ovarian cancers. 
                 The Alliance received many calls and requests to comment from media outlets; expand this story for links to some of our news coverage.
            </p>

        </div>

        <div class="plus">
            <img src="http://www.ovariancancer.org/wp-content/themes/ovariancancer/images/plus2.png" style="width:33px;height:33px;"/>
        </div>

    </div>
  <div class="extarCOntent" style="display:none">
                    <p>  Angelina Jolie Pitt recently announced that she has had her ovaries and fallopian tubes removed in order to reduce her risk of ovarian cancer. 
                 Ms. Jolie Pitt had previous shared that she has a mutation in the BRCA gene, which increases her risk of breast and ovarian cancers. 
                 The Alliance received many calls and requests to comment from media outlets; expand this story for links to some of our news coverage.
            </p>
            </div>


</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.event_profit,.extarCOntent{
  background: #ecece9;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  height:180px;
  }  

.plus{
  width:5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.event_content p{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.maincontainer{
 width:100%;
 display: -webkit-inline-box;

}
.event_image{
  width: 15%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top:1%;
}

.event_content{
 width: 70%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

***JavaScript***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".plus").click(function(){

        $(".extarCOntent").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f1cnh8r/5/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how that page using jquery to show and hide the div:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".plus").click(function() 
    {

        jQuery( this).parent().toggleClass( "open" );
        jQuery( this).parent().find('.secret').toggle("slow");
        //jQuery(".secret", this).toggle("slow");
   });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0g35mot8/1/

Answer (score 1):

This Will Work as You want 


## #Live Demo#

**Jquery :**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".plus").click(function() 
    {

        jQuery( this).parent().toggleClass( "open" );
        jQuery( this).parent().find('.secret').toggle("slow");

   });

});
```